# What is different between applicatoin.properties and yml in spring boot application

Tags: java

I am bit confused which on should I use and When ?

I tried both but getting my spring boot application is running fine with both type of configuration file.

Comment: Both are fine. It depends on which format you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some key differences between the two files:

***properties***

- Key and values separated by equal or color
- Easy to read by humans
- Supports primitive types like strings and numbers
- Supports flat and non-hierarchical structure

***yml/yaml***

- Contains key and value pairs
- Human readable format
- Supports Integer, Strings, Maps, and Lists
- Supports hierarchical structure

YAML has more superset features when compared with properties in features like types(List and Map), type safety, and hierarchical structure.

It is always best to choose yaml with wider programming language support.